# Angular-router not works at vercel

Tags: angular, express, angular-ui-router, vercel

I'm working on the serverless web MEAN and I'm trying to publish on vercel. When I'm trying to access some route through the navigation menu, the router is working fine, but when I try to access that route only http://vercel-dev/some-route they show me error 404.

Here's my vercel configuration:

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds":
    [
        {
            "src": "backend/build/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node",
            "config":
            {
                "includeFiles":
                [
                    "backend/build/src/**"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "src": "frontend/dist/frontend/**",
            "use": "@vercel/static"
        }
    ],
    "routes":
    [
        {
            "src": "/api/(.*)",
            "dest": "backend/build/index.js"
        },
        {
            "src": "/",
            "dest": "frontend/dist/frontend/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.+)",
            "dest": "frontend/dist/frontend/$1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For work with routes in your SPA, in the root of your repository create a vercel.json with the following

```
vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/.*", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```

Read more examples:
https://dev.to/alexmercedcoder/deploying-react-angular-svelte-and-vue-to-netlify-vercel-496j

Comment: Actually I posted vercel.json configuration up there,
I try with :

vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/.*", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```
and also with 

    {"src": "/[^.]",, "dest": "/index.html" }

still not working